# Display a value from a core data many to one relationship in a table using bindings

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a core data project which has a fairly simple data model but there is one feature that I am having trouble implementing. It is a really basic feature so I know it must be able to be implemented but I am, unfortunately, stumped.

Rather than burden you with the project details I will instead use an employee scenario to explain.

Here is the data model


Entity = Employee 
Attributes:
firstName
lastName

Relationships:
grade
department


Entity = Grade
Attributes:
grade

Relationships:
employeeGrade


Entity = Department
Attributes:
department

Relationships:
employeeDepartment



employeeGrade is a many-to-one relationship with grade from the Employee Entity

employeeDepartment is a many-to-one relationship with department from the Employee Entity

All attributes are strings.

I have a table set to add grades to the grade entity.

I have another table beneath the grade table to display the list of employees who have the grade that is selected in the grade table.

I want to display the first name, last name and department for each employee in this table. By using array controllers and bindings in IB, displaying the first and last names is no problem but getting the department to display is what is proving problematic for me. It is as you can see a many to one relationship and I cannot figure out how to set this up with bindings so that the department for the employee is shown in the table.

I can easily populate a popupmenu cell with the all departments but I simply want to display only the appropriate department in a text cell

I know the answer must be simple but after days of searching the net and experimenting I am lost.

Comment: What Model Key Paths have you tried? Looks to me that `department.department` should work.

Comment: Yep. That did it. Thanks a lot Paul. I knew it was simple but had got totally lost. Another Duh! moment I am afraid.